# How to understand the statement "The only exception is when the two declarations define a getter-setter pair" in the MDN documentation

Tags: javascript

Per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields) (emphasis mine):

> There are some additional syntax restrictions:
>
> - All private identifiers declared within a class must be unique. The namespace is shared between static and instance properties. **The only
>   exception is when the two declarations define a getter-setter pair.**
> - The private identifier cannot be `#constructor`.

How to interpret the bolded statement? This is how I understand it:

```js
class MyClass {
  static #privateProperty = 10; 

  #privateProperty = 20; 

  get #privateProperty() {}
  set #privateProperty(value) {}
}
```

But:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier '#privateProperty' has already been declared
```

Can you help me explain this sentence and provide an explanation using code?

Comment: The getter and setter are irrelevant in your example, they're _not_ named `#privateProperty`.

Comment: "All private identifiers" then later... "Private properties are declared with # names (pronounced "hash names"), which are identifiers prefixed with #." then scroll down to see the getter setter pair example with the same id `get #decoratedMessage() `...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The MDN text means that a given private property name `#something` can only be declared once in a class, either as a `static` property or an instance property. When the property is intended to be accessed via getter and setter functions, the name can (and really must) appear twice:

```
  get #something() {
    return // whatever
  }
  set #something(value) {
    whatever(value);
  }
```

That's it; it's a pretty simple rule. The way that getter and setter methods are declared directly implies the need for what looks *a little bit* like two declarations for the same property. Your code gets errors because you are trying to use `#privateProperty` as a `static` property, an instance property, and a getter/setter pair. Pick one.